# Try to shut down, log out occurs?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, logout

On my windows 8.1 pc, I try and shut down, all that happens is I log out sometimes
I am definately pressing shut down :P
no other users are logged in (that's what I thought the error may be)
Can anyone suggest any solutions or what the possible problem is?

Comment: This might be a missing driver for the power management system.  Is this an off the shelf PC or home made?

Comment: That's what I thought but I have tried searching for drivers in the driver manager service, it's off the shelf but I have modified it with a new graphics card, IIRC then the problem existed before I put in the graphics card.